# Redirect default program to another program when a file opens in Windows OS

Tags: windows, redirect, process

This is only under windows env.
As I know windows os identifies associated application of a particular file by file extension.
Like wise each file (binary) starting with corresponding symbols ("starting symbols"). For an example .JPG starts with ÿØÿà. Let say I open this .JPG file in a Hex editor or a Text editor and then I change that starting symbols into another file type. for an example I can change ÿØÿà to .Eß£ (.mkv). So when I double click on the .JPG the Windows Photo Viewer says there are some errors or similar message. So I need to get some information about the application that tries to open that kind of a file. If I can, I need to open that file using the application that associated with "starting symbols".

Briefly when I open .JPG I need to open a default video player .mkv files. But It may not work for this example. Because I changed only the "starting symbols" of my .JPG.

Please give me any idea to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing this, or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to encrypt files and remains the encrypted file as the original (original should be deleted). So when I double click the encrypted file It should open in my encryption-decryption program. But when you open the file It tries to open it using It's extension. Actually It should be opened in decryption program.

Comment: I can do the encryption. It is not about the encryption. I need to replace my original file by my encrypted file(same file name with ext). If it is so then my encrypted file won't open with my en-decryption program due to the extension. That's the problem I got.

Answer (score 2):

When you encrypt the file, give it a new extension. e.g. `Picture.jpg` becomes `Picture.encrypted-jpg`. You then register as the handler for `encrypted-jpg`, decrypt the file, then launch the normal `jpg` handler.

Comment: That is very correct. But I need the encrypted file-name as the original. e.g : Original -> Picture.jpg , Encrypted -> Picture.jpg . So actually after the encryption you won't see the difference between the original file and the new one. original should be deleted after the encryption.

Comment: But the next program to register for `jpg` will see your encrypted files and will not know what to do with them. The way to say you want to be called when somebody opens a `jpg` file is to register as the `jpg` handler. But this assumes that the file really is a `jpg`. By putting a non-`jpg` in a file marked `jpg`, you're violating the type system.

Comment: Something like that. That's why I'm trying to read the header and redirect to particular handler. If really it is .jpg then calls the jpg handler and if it is an encrypted one then that one.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that you are going opposite to how the system is designed, which is why you're having trouble. If you create nonstandard JPGs, then when the user goes to "Set your default programs" and says "I want to open JPGs with Adobe Photoshop", Adobe Photoshop will say "Hey, this isn't a JPG."

Comment: Think about Linux OS. There is no such a matter. So actually there should be a way to do it. Because windows hide something. When open a file the initial handler only see the ext. But If I can override that handler or rewrite a new initial handler then I can read the file header and the I can redirect to the corresponding program. I don't know whether this is possible or not. Somehow I'm looking for a way to do it. Thanks for the comments. If you found something about this please put comment. Really I want to know about this.

Comment: If you want to redirect to another program, then go ahead and redirect to another program. I'm just saying that if the user changes the default `jpg` handler to a third program, that third program will not know that when it registers as the new default handler for `jpg` files, it is really getting fake `jpg` files. If Linux has a model for file type pre-handlers, then great, but Windows doesn't, at least not at the shell level. I guess you could write a file system filter that modifies file content? Though that typically is done only by malware.

Answer (score 1):

When the shell is asked to perform a verb on a file, the shell does not use the contents of the file to determine which app to pass it to. The file extension is what determines how the file will be treated.

You wish to use the contents of the file to influence which app processes a shell verb. In order to do so you would need to create a launcher app that reads the file header and then decides which app to pass the file on to. You would assign your launcher app as the handler app for all file extensions that you were interested in.

Although you could do this, it would be much easier just to set the file extension appropriately.

Comment: So if I create a handler then I need to override the default windows handler by my custom handler if there is a default handler. So if I can do so then the custom handler need to read the content of all the files that we open. Am I correct? So then it would be a cpu time consuming or something. Because now the custom handler has to read each and every file content instead of identifying the extension like default handler.

Comment: You have understood what I say correctly. You need to replace the default handler for each file extension with your own. As for performance, reading a few bytes from the beginning of a file is very very fast. I doubt you'd notice the difference. Just make sure that you app can start up very quickly. I'd use native code.

Comment: Note that once another application takes over the jpg association, not only will your handler no longer be in charge of jpg, the other application will not be able to open the file either. Lose/lose.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this sort of thing is to replace the files with [reparse points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365503%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

The downside is that this involves writing a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968), i.e., an operating system extension, which is a whole level of trouble above and beyond ordinary application programming.  (Since Windows already does file encryption, I doubt it would be worth the effort.)